# Android Capture Image From Camera throwing null pointer at data.getExtras()

Tags: android

I am using the same code as  https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html 
  I am capturing image from the camera and saving it to imageView. Everything is looking fine but I am getting Bundle as null onActivityResult. I have added all the permissions and path as mentioned in the above link My Code is below

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    import com.tcg.garageapplication.R;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private static final String TAG ="ImageCaptureCamera" ;
        static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
        ImageView ivSimpleTest;
        String mCurrentPhotoPath;
        Uri photoURI;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_capture_camera);
            ivSimpleTest = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_simple_test);
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }
        protected void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
                if (photoFile != null) {
                   photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                            "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                            photoFile);
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                ivSimpleTest.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            }
        }
        private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
            File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);

            mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
            Log.e(TAG,"Value of IMAGEpATH "+mCurrentPhotoPath);
            return image;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intent extra `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` with the camera intent will write the captured image to that path and it will not return the bitmap in the onActivityResult method.

If you want to pass the extra paramater `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` with the camera intent, you have to save the fileUri as a member variable so then it can later be accessed in onActivityResult()

Hope it helps!